# AWS Cognito delete all users from a user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How can we delete all users from a specific user pool in AWS Cognito using AWS CLI?

Answer (score 34):

try with below:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID |
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read uname1; do
  echo "Deleting $uname1";
  aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username $uname1;
done
```

Comment: I tried this on windows and it was not working, that's why I posted the other one.

Comment: Works great on my mac, and probably anything UNIX-like.

Comment: You can run this on the AWS CloudShell available on the console.

Comment: you need to install jq to make this work.

Comment: Absolute legend! Copy and pasted this in AWS cloudshell console, replaced the user_pool_id and BOOM! Magic!

Comment: If jq is facing error, check if you default config it to output yaml. If it is the case, make sure to use --output json on the list command

Answer (score 25):

In order to speed up deletion, I modified @GRVPrasad's answer to use [xargs -P](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) which will farm deletions out to multiple processes.

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID | jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' | xargs -n 1 -P 5 -I % bash -c "echo Deleting %; aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username %"
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution that worked perfectly and was very fast too.  I'd upvote it 100000x if possible.

Comment: nice solution, thanks a lot, worked very nice for me on Mac Os as well

Comment: also worked on AWS CloudShell

Answer (score 6):

Here is a bash version based on @ajilpm's batch script:

```sh
# deleteAllUsers.sh
COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID=$1

aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID |
jq -r '.Users | .[] | .Username' |
while read user; do
  aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username $user
  echo "$user deleted"
done
```

You must have *jq* installed and remember to make the script executable: `chmod +x deleteAllUsers.sh`.

The user pool id can be provided as a command line argument: `./deleteAllUsers.sh COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID`.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I created a script to do it from Windows CMD if you have AWS Cli installed and configured, which will delete all the users page by page, so you need to run it till all users are removed.

You need to have [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) downloaded and its path added to system env path for the following to work.

---delete.bat---

```
@echo off setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in 
  ('aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID ^| 
    jq -r ".Users | .[] | .Username"')
do 
  (aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username %%I 
   echo %%I deleted)
```

---delete.bat---

Comment: @Marcin, I'm posting on this site for the first time, so I thought posting it in a question answer format would help people to find it easily and that is the format I see throughout the site. If there is another format, please let me know and I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cannot add comment. I had same requirement and slight modification in command mentioned by ajilpm worked in windows 10 for me. You need to download jq.exe and keep on path in command line

```
---Start.bat---

@echo off setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id us-west-2_O7rRBQ5rr --profile dev-hb ^| jq -r ".Users | .[] | .Username"') do ( aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id us-west-2_O7rRBQ5rr --username %%I --profile dev-hb)

---delete.bat---
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python and boto3:
I use email as username

```
import boto3 as aws
import pandas as pd

client_cognito = aws.client('cognito-idp')
getProperties = pd.read_csv('CognitoUsers.csv',header=0)
usernames = getProperties['email']

for username in usernames:
    response = client_cognito.admin_delete_user(
        UserPoolId="us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
        Username = username,
    )
```

you need login in aws-cli with your AWS Access Key ID & AWS Secret Access Key

Answer (score 0):

I've created the following script based on the answer of @Richard. Note I had to set `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` to make sure that the script doesn't stop at invalid characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID=__XXX__

export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

RUN=1
until [ $RUN -eq 0 ] ; do
echo "Listing users"
USERS=`aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID | grep Username | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/\"//g' | sed -e 's/,//g'`
if [ ! "x$USERS" = "x" ] ; then
  echo "$USERS" | xargs -n 1 -P 5 -I % bash -c "echo Deleting %; aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username %"
else
    echo "Done, no more users"
    RUN=0
fi
done
```